# How to manually request the clangd or implement ClangdServer for code complettion

Tags: language-server-protocol, clangd

I've installed clangd for MS VS Code and everything works fine.
I wonder how can I manually request clangd via language server protocol?
Or is there capability to programmatically include ClangdServer in my code, then add the header for requesting the structure of the code?
Thank you.